# How can I upgrade to core 9?

Tags: drush

I have Drupal 8.8.* and I would like to migrate to Drupal 9 using Drush 8. I know, we can use composer however I just wanted to confirm, whether we can do by using Drush command?

I tried using Drush but it's showing no updates available.

```
$ drush pm-update drupal-9.0.0
Update information last refreshed: Thu, 06/11/2020 - 11:42
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message                     
 Drupal  8.9.0              8.9.0             Specified version not found 


No code updates available.
```

Comment: You can't. Drupal 9 requires Drush 10. And Drush 10 won't let you update manually, if I remember it right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I manually upgrade my Drupal 8 site to Drupal 9?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294372/how-can-i-manually-upgrade-my-drupal-8-site-to-drupal-9)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. `drush pm-update` has been deprecated for a while. The command is still available in the Drush 8.x branch but in later revisions it only [exists as a signpost](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/27eaeafd3c9f188dc2f1cf581b039ede578e2166/src/Commands/LegacyCommands.php#L80) to inform the user how to move to Composer:

> The pm-updatecode command was removed. Please see `composer update --dry-run` and `composer update`.

Noting that Drush 8 [isn't supporting revisions past 8.3.x](https://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/#drupal-compatibility) or 9.x, you should look into upgrading Drush and moving to a Composer-driven upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

While this not neither bulletproof, here is what I did now to move from Drupal 8 to 9 using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

1. make sure you are on the latest drupal 8 version (let's call this d8)
2. verify you meet the d9 server requirements: php min 7.3, mysql min 5.7.8
3. do yourself a favor and make a database backup (I did not out of lazyness)
4. create a new project standard drupal 9 somewhere: `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project d9` (let'S call it d9)
5. use `composer require drupal/module-name-xy` in the new d9 folder for every contrib module the d8 site is using - chances are pretty high, that they are all compatible with 9 already - if not composer will tell you and ideally also some options to fix it
6. optional: if you are not using [drush](https://www.drush.org/latest/install/) jet: `composer require drush/drush`
7. add `core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9` to your custom `my-module.info` and `my-theme.info` files
8. override the d8 `composer.json` with the d9 one
9. run `composer update` in the d9 folder - now the main update is happening
10. some files that have been changed by this automatically might need a rollback depending on your local deveopment settings: `web/sites/development.services.yml` and `web/.htaccess` in particular
11. update the DB (I'm using drush): `drush --yes updb`
12. start drupal and check the php error logs - you might encounter a few coding issues in your custom modules and thems, but they should be relatively straight foreward to identify and fix.
13. in the end have a short look to `/admin/reports/status`

Fingers crossed and best of luck!

(feel free to edit and extend this answer to make the best possible upgrade guide out of it)